# continuing congruence equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do you solve this congruence equation? 
$$3\equiv -4a\pmod {13}$$

What I did was : 
Applying symmetry property 
$$ -4a\equiv 3\pmod {13} $$ Since **gcd(13,4) = 1** we multiply both sides by inverse of $4\pmod {13}$ 
$$-a\equiv30\pmod{13}$$
$$a\equiv-30\pmod{13}$$
How can I continue from this point?
$ a + 30 = 13k$ doesn't help me.

Comment: You are almost done, you just need to simplify $-30\pmod{13}$.

Comment: You could directly use the inverse of $-4$, which is $3$.

Comment: $-30\equiv -17...\bmod 13$. just keep going until you get a number in between $0$ and $12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more handy solution: 
3 = -4a (mod 13) 
9 = -12a (mod 13) 
9 = a (mod 13)     <--i think you could figure it out.

so , a = 9, 21,......

Answer (score 1):

What I didn't know was that $-30\pmod{13} =9 $ is not equal to $30\pmod{13}=4$ 

So we can write the above expression as
$$ a\equiv9\pmod{13}$$
$$ a = 9$$